# how to delete not saved data but i have assigned this data with build or new in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-api

I have assigned record like this

```
profile_image = current_user.profile_images.build(params_profile_image)
```

But I don't want to save this record any more. Now how can I delete this **profile_image** unsaved record ?

Answer (score 1):

For the variable `profile_image`, you don't need to do anything, it will be deleted once your code exit the block of where the variable is declared.

If you don't want to do anything else with `current_user` then you can just leave it too, and after the code exit the block where the variable is declared it will be gone, and next time you retrieve `current_user` it will be a new copy without the unsaved changes.

However if you want to continue using `current_user` you can do `current_user.restore_attributes` this will revert all unsaved changes to `current_user`. If you have other unsaved changes that you need to keep. I would recommend you to restructure the code to not call `current_user.profile_images.build(params_profile_image)` but rather `Foo.build(params_profile_image)` where `Foo` is the model class for `profile_images`. And only assign `current_user.profile_images=profile_image` once you're sure you need to save.